# How to create a multiview control in asp.net and manipulate it at run time?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Example:

```
<asp:MultiView
        id="MultiView1"
        ActiveViewIndex="1"
        Runat="server">
        <asp:View ID="View1" runat="server" >
            <iframe id="v1" runat="server" src='http://www.w3schools.com' style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>        
        <asp:View ID="View2" runat="server">
            <iframe id="Iframe1" runat="server" src='http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_intro.asp' style="border: None; height: 100%; width: 100%;"></iframe>
        </asp:View>        
        <asp:View ID="View3" runat="server">
            <br />This is the third view
            <br />This is the third view
            <br />This is the third view
            <br />This is the third view
        </asp:View>
        <asp:View ID="View4" runat="server">
            <br />This is the third view
            <br />This is the third view
            <br />This is the third view
            <br />This is the third view
        </asp:View>        
    </asp:MultiView>
```

Concerns:

1. How to create this multiview structure at run time?
2. Is there any alternative for iframe that can be use inside multiview?
3. Can I use one multiview view for say 2 or more menu?
4. How to reference and manipulate multiview using javascript or jquery?

Please help me with this.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this is similar to your last question: [How to Show/Hide Menu Item and how to create it at run time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16930429). You may also want to look at this MSDN article for a discussion regarding adding controls programmatically: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1(v=vs.100).aspx

Below is an example of how to populate a `MultiView` control with `View` controls dynamically.

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create View.
    View myView = new View();

    // Create controls.
    Label myLabel = new Label();
    myLabel.Text = "<b>Test</b>";

    // Add controls to View.
    myView.Controls.Add(myLabel);


    //Add view to MultiView.
    MultiView1.Views.Add(myView);
    MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 0;
}
```

The above logic is the same for adding any controls to a page programmatically.

You can manipulate the `MultiView` control the same way using server-side code by referencing specific Views with an index:

```
Label myLabel = new Label();
myLabel.Text = "<b>Test</b>";

MultiViewDemo.Views[0].Controls(myLabel);
```

You should then be able to manipulate any HTML elements in those views using jQuery as normal.

Using multiple `Menu` controls in a `MultiView` depends on your requirements.

In regards to the `iframe`, I'm not sure what you would be looking for in an alternative, but you should be able to manipulate your `iframe` controls with server-side code since you have added the `runat="server"` attribute to them.

Comment: Thank you! You are always helpful.

Comment: This will definitely help me. :-)